Plotting a chirp square signal in python
Wikipedia definition: A chirp is a signal in which the frequency increases (up-chirp) or decreases (down-chirp) with time. In some sources, the term chirp is used interchangeably with sweep signal.
I need to create a square signal segment with the following parameters:

duration of the signal
frequency at start and stop
amplitude at start and stop
duty cycle at start and stop

For example, a signal that starts at 10 Hz, with an amplitude of 10%, and a duty cycle of 20%, and that stops 60 sec later at 20 Hz, with an amplitude of 50%, and a duty cycle of 80%. All variations are linear.
Scipy provides the chirp function that constructs a chirp sine where you can specify t0,f0 and t1,f1. I would like to find an equivalent for square signal with the added bonus of also linearly changing the duty cycle.
I am looking at to sweep signal starting from something like
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

x = numpy.linspace(0, 10, 1000)
y = numpy.array([1 if math.floor(2 * t) % 2 == 0 else 0 for t in x])
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()

just need to find the right equation creating the numpy array. Any idea welcome

No need for additional functions: it's a square wave, so if you know your zero transitions (which you do, they are the same as for a sine wave) then you're pretty much done. Instead of the amplitude ramping up and down, it's just an instant transition from max amplitude to max amplitude with the opposite sign. Then you zero out everything that falls outside the duty interval.

This sound like a good approach. I was thinkig of using np.convolve of np.fromfunction. To elaborate on your answer to get the right duty cycle I could use a specific value on the sin rather than zero crossing.

What does "duty cycle" mean in this context? e.g. does 80% duty cycle mean on for 80 milliseconds, off for 20 milliseconds? Or does it mean on for 8 seconds, off for 2 seconds?

the cycle ratio is a frequency-independent ratio that indicates the ratio between high and low time. for example, for a 1Hz signal, if the ratio is 0.5 (50%), the signal is high for 500 ms and low for 500 ms.

"duty cycle" has defined technical meanings. -- if you need to linearly vary the duty cycle, generate a triangle signal (symmetric for phase considerations), then threshold it with a time-varying threshold. that'll result in a square wave of desired duty cycle.

Converting the chirp function (sinusoidal) to square wave is relatively easy. Just convert the values in the numpy table to 0 and 1 as Mike pointed out in the comments.
What was a little more complicated was modulating the width of the converted signal according to a linear function of duty cycle variation. All you have to do is compare the output chirp signal (based on a cosine) with the cosine of the instantaneous value of the linear duty cycle function.
The first plot shows the chrip signal varying from 6 to 1 Hz over 10 seconds.
The second plot shows this signal converted with duty=50% (zero crossing).
The third plot shows the charp conversion with a duty cycle varying from 10 to 90% over 10 seconds.
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import chirp, spectrogram
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

time_start, time_end = 0, 10
freq_start, freq_end = 6 , 1
duty_start, duty_end = 0.1, 0.9
samples = 1000
time = np.linspace(time_start, time_end, samples)
duty = np.linspace(duty_start,duty_end, samples)
cos_chirp = chirp(time, f0=freq_start, f1=freq_end, t1=time_end, method='linear')
sqr_chirp = np.array([1 if chirp(t, t1=time_end, f0=freq_start, f1=freq_end, method="linear") > 0 else -1 for t in time])
sqr_chirp_duty = np.array([1 if chirp(t, t1=time_end, f0=freq_start, f1=freq_end, method="linear") > 
                      np.cos(0 + np.pi*duty[i]) else -1 for i, t in enumerate(time)])
fig, axs = plt.subplots(3)
axs[0].plot(time, cos_chirp)
axs[1].plot(time, sqr_chirp)
axs[2].plot(time, sqr_chirp_duty)

plt.show()



Not to be a Debbie Downer, but this is only an approximation of a square wave chirp. Because the corners of the square wave will seldom align with sample boundaries, the frequency will almost always be slightly wrong. The higher the sampling rate, the better the approximation. A small detail, but worth noting. The digital emulation of discontinuous analog waveforms is a research field unto itself (at least in computer music applications).

Actually my solution was over complicated for no reason here is an easier a less approximate solution
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def pwm_gen(
    t: np.ndarray, t1: float, f0: float, f1: float, d: np.ndarray
) -> np.ndarray:
    return np.array(
        [
            0 if p % 1 > d[i] else 1
            for i, p in enumerate(f0 * t + 0.5 * ((f1 - f0) / t1) * t * t)
        ]
    )

samples = 1000
time = np.linspace(0, 10, samples)
duty = np.linspace(0.1,0.8, samples)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(time, pwm_gen(time, 10, 1, 3, duty))
plt.show()


